# inserting data into a table using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, oracle

im trying to insert data using python (pyodbc) into my database but i keep getting errors like missing comma and others

i tried to use the variable "linea" instead of all the values but doesnt work

```
for linea in nintendo:
        if(linea[0]!='id'):
            print(linea)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Nintendo (juegoid,nombrejuego,generos,desarrolladores,publicadoras,fechapublicacion,exclusividad,ventasglobales,rating) VALUES (linea[0],linea[1],linea[2],linea[3],linea[4],linea[5],linea[6],linea[7],linea[8]);")
            print("data loaded")
```

this contains "linea":

['1', '#Breakforcist Battle', 'Party', 'Lucid Sheep Games', 'Lucid Sheep Games', 'April 12, 2018', 'No', '', '']

Answer (score 0):

You missed the Values Keyword

```
INSERT INTO Nintendo **Values** (juegoid,nombrejuego,generos,desarrolladores,publicadoras,fechapublicacion,exclusividad,ventasglobales,rating) VALUES (linea[0],linea[1],linea[2],linea[3],linea[4],linea[5],linea[6],linea[7],linea[8]);
```

Also you have to commit the data using  cursor.commit

Comment: *Values* is in OP's original SQL statement.

Comment: apologies.. didnt see it in full.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Python, you cannot interpolate variables like list values *directly* inside a string. You must use some type of string formatting method including `%` modulo operator (deprecated use), `str.format()`, or even the newer `F-string` in 3.6+.

Specifically in DB-APIs, you should be parameterizing queries where variables are binded to placeholders on the `cursor.execute` call:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
sql = """INSERT INTO Nintendo (juegoid, nombrejuego, generos, desarrolladores, publicadoras,
                              fechapublicacion, exclusividad, ventasglobales, rating)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

# BIND PARAMS
cursor.execute(sql, params=linea[0:8])
conn.commit()

print("data loaded")
```

Comment: I tried the str.format method 
`string = "INSERT INTO Nintendo (juegoid,nombrejuego,generos,desarrolladores,publicadoras,fechapublicacion,exclusividad,ventasglobales,rating) VALUES ({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{});"
            sql=string.format(linea[0],linea[1],linea[2],linea[3],linea[4],linea[5],linea[6],linea[7],linea[8])
            cursor.execute(sql)`
now im getting the ORA-00911 error

Comment: Why are you not parameterizing? Avoid string interpolation in SQL. Your current attempt does not include quotes for string columns which can be avoided with parameters. Please advise why my solution did not work. Post full error.